# Should (/does) metaphysics care about physics?

Tags: metaphysics

A. I have met the criticism that metaphysical theories doesn't/shouldn't care about (natural) science (=physics mostly, if not only), as in it doesn't really have a direct relation to it (such criticism was noted on several of my questions, and is pretty rational and probably true).

But I must admit, I'm rather confused. I'll start with a quote from Chalmers' article "Idealism and the Mind-body Problem":

> The basic motivations for cosmopsychism and cosmic idealism are
>   closely related to the motivations for panpsychism and micro-idealism.
>   As with [panpsychism and micro-idealism] views, cosmopsychism and
>   cosmic idealism can be jointly motivated through *the success of
>   science* [my marking], the problem of consciousness, and the
>   inscrutability of matter.

Now, this seem to be clearly connecting metaphysics with science (and not the only place; Chalmers also talks extensively about the relations of different idealistic theories with quantum mechanics, specifically quantum entanglement - for example: "[in talks about what Chalmers calls macro-idealism, meaning idealism in the 'normal-sized' bodies, such as humans and perhaps animals] it is also not easy to see how quantum entanglement can stably remain somewhere around the person level rather than spreading to the cosmic level...).

From the article (and from what I previously thought metaphysics were), it seems as though metaphysical theories need to at least be coherent with existing scientific theories (if not to be able to explain and predict scientific facts). This seems rather weird, as I got the impression from the arguments I had in this site that metaphysical theories *shouldn't* meddle with scientific theories, in such a way that there should be a strict distinction between the two fields. So what happened here? Did I understand Chalmers wrong? Did I understand the arguments wrong? (Did Chalmers understand metaphysics wrong?)

B. [considering separating to a different question, tell me in the comments if I should:] there's another thing I'm not sure about in metaphysics. It's the fundamental understanding of "meta" in metaphysics - I hear that it means "before" physics, as in what's the basis for physics, what's the underlying systematic view of the world. But if I remember correctly, metaphysics was originally coined by Aristotle as the next book of his physics - meaning that metaphysics is actually *after* physics. Any help here please?

Comment: What I am getting is that metaphysics should take results of science into account, perhaps even be motivated by them. German idealists instead had a dream of "better" Science drawn according to their principles, it did not go well. In Aristotle's corpus what was after Physics the editors labeled Metaphysics, it discussed "grander" matters. Whether one goes from the general to the concrete or the other way depends entirely on one's purposes.

Comment: @Conifold didn't you specifically say that metaphysics should be strictly unrelated to science? If we go the path of "should take results of science into account, be motivated by them", wouldn't we come to the conclusion that metaphysics can be rejected by scientific findings, which I clearly remember some here argued against?

Comment: I don't know if I can put it into an answer, but one might argue a metaphysicist *should* stay away from physics as a manner of marketing, to distinguish one from those boring scientists.  Beyond that, isn't half of the fun of metaphysics trying to figure out what one *should* do in the first place?

Comment: Where did I say that??? I distinctly remember saying that it can serve as an incubator of scientific theories, among many other things. Metaphysics can be rejected/abandoned, as happened multiple times in the past, and scientific findings can play a role in that, although usually indirectly since metaphysical claims are not testable, and that is hardly the only way.  Absolute idealism was broadly rejected early in the 20-th century because it was seen as too rationalistic and detached from life, not because of science.

Comment: @Conifold I'm sorry, I probably confused you with PeterJ in his comment on the "science forces us materialism" question - "Materialism is a metaphysical conjecture that has nothing to do with science", and I probably misinterpreted that too as a view that metaphysics "has nothing to do with science". So now I'm even more confused then before, sadly. Can you elaborate and explain the relation between metaphysics and science? Maybe in the chat, but it seem rather very related to the question so here might be better.

Comment: I would assume that one cannot hold a broader theory that contradicts a more specific theory one also holds.  So physics can at least controvert a metaphysical idea by creating specific effects inconsistent with it.  (The two may contradict in theory, but both claim to apply to observed phenomena.  And physics creates technologies which create physical change in the world.)  At the same time (if you buy Kuhn), physics has a paradigm, which draws its contents from metaphysics at the time of a paradigm shift, having no other source material.  So the two do seem to be rather intimately related.

Comment: As I see it, neither of these can push the other around, but they both have to explain the same experiences.  If you go in a Popper/Kuhn direction, physics also has to lag metaphysics, or contradict most of the alternatives, because it has to choose a metaphysical foundation for its definitions and stick with those until they are controverted.

Comment: I find Steven Weinberg's position... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RjF4UBgITs ...on the physics/metaphysics relationship quite reasonable, and, in my limited experience about that, pretty much correct. I especially identify with his (on the video and paraphrased here) remark that physicists have the healthy experience of being proven wrong, whereas philosophers never do. And sometimes the so-called (by them) scientific interpretations they take exemplify their lack of that healthy experience.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Weinberg doesn't know a lot about philosophy. Physicists all have a metaphysical baggage that they take on board with their theories, and metaphysics of science just tries to make these commitments explicit and coherent. They can be proven wrong by arguments. Physicists like Weinberg just want to leave their implicit commitments unexamined.

Comment: The relation between physics and metaphysics is a big topic. A famous (though polemical) piece on this that you can read is "everything must go" by Ladyman and Ross (first chapters), where they argue that metaphysics should be informed by science.

Comment: I use "metaphysics" interchangeably with "ontology" in a common clay/garden variety sense, it is not PeterJ's Metaphysics as articulating True Reality behind the curtain. Perhaps, [What are some real-life applications of metaphysics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32914/what-are-some-real-life-applications-of-metaphysics/33980#33980) post will help.

Comment: @Conifold so you say only ontological metaphysics matter? That makes the whole discussion different I think.

Comment: Again, where did I say that? First, metaphysics has science unrelated uses, such as grounding ethical beliefs, inspiring art and literature, etc. Second, Metaphysics falls under metaphysics even in the narrow sense, as speculation about being on the grandest scale. Although, I will say that my skepticism of speculations grows in direct proportion to their grandness.

Comment: @Conifold so I'm not sure I understand your first line - "I use metaphysics interchangeably with ontology". Also, I haven't noticed before, you distinct *M*etaphysics and *m*etaphysics? (and btw when I say "ontological metaphysics" I don't necessarily mean only science related, just everything that is "ontological".)

Comment: I do not follow the question.

Comment: @Conifold you say you use metaphysics interchangeably with ontology right?

Comment: @QuentinRuyant While I'm no expert (not even an amateur) on the subject, it seems to me (in my limited capacity) that you're projecting metaphysics' own shortcomings onto physics. While physicists often suggest interpretation-after-interpretation of their formalisms up the whazoo, they usually aren't particularly committed (inevitable exceptions notwithstanding). It's (again in my limited experience) more often philosophers who get unjustifiably committed to their positions/interpretations. Anyway, see my longer-winded (wouldn't fit as a comment) attempt at an answer, below...

Comment: @JohnForkosh this is a complex matter but the failure of positivist programs tend to show that there's a continuity between science and metaphysics. The main reason is, roughly, that the core principles and laws of a theory are never confirmed or refuted directly by any experiment (only models that combine all laws/principles plus auxiliary hypotheses, implicit assumptions and practical knowledge are) So merely saying that a theory is true or approximately true, that is, using the theory as a description of reality, commits one somehow and the question of metaphysics is: to what?

Comment: Metaphysics and physics should agree.at all times but usually they don't overlap much. They may seem to overlap where physicists make metaphysical conjectures such as materialism, dualism, atheism, realism and suchlike, but these are not scientific theories. Theories must work in both physics and metaphysics to be plausible in either. Metaphysics surrounds and encompasses physics so comes before and after, regardless of Aristotle's order of business. .   .

Comment: @QuentinRuyant Your comment at first correctly says "model", but then you go on to incorrectly (everything's "in my opinion") say "description of reality". Now, **>>that<<** (interpreting a formalism/theory as a "description of reality") would indeed be a big, fat **>>commitment<<** (using your word). But you're entirely wrong thinking that's what physicists typically do (with inevitable exceptions). Rather, theories and accompanying formalisms are (exactly like you said) models, that work in some regime of experience, to the extent that they're experimentally tested. And then eventually fail.

Comment: One can speculate big or one can speculate small, there is no sharp boundary between the two or established terminological distinction. I tend to use metaphysics/ontology towards the lower part of the spectrum because it is more common, but it is by no means a convention that everybody follows.

Comment: @Conifold so what's your definition of metaphysics? Speculation theories about nature? In contrast to science, which is "testable" (natural science, nowadays) theories? So the difference will be the speculativity/testability aspect?

Comment: @JohnForkosh I'm actually very sympathetic to your views. I would say most physicists are pragmatic when it comes to the interpretation of theories. But even what pragmatism amounts to needs to be clarified. What I agree on is that contemporary metaphysics is very much on the realist ("description of reality") side, which has not always been the case in history of philosophy, and that these questions do not bother scientists that much. What I would disagree on is that there's no interesting questions to be asked on these topics, and that philosophers cannot be "proven wrong".

Comment: @QuentinRuyant side note - I hear idealism is making a comeback

Comment: It doesn't have to be about nature, the traditional question it answers is "what is", nature is just part of it. So are potentially values, mental, spiritual, ideal and cultural entities, etc., depending on one's perspective.

Comment: @Conifold let me refine: what does metaphysics of nature mean?

Comment: Presumably, describing what is in nature.

Comment: @Conifold how is that different from natural science then?

Comment: Natural science is interested not so much in what nature *is* as in making predictions and general claims about its behavior. Of course, *interpretations* of scientific theories, especially fundamental theories like general relativity and quantum mechanics, or cosmology and evolutionary biology, do get into speculating how the world is, but that is exactly where they cross into metaphysics.

Comment: @Conifold OK thank you, this is exactly what I was thinking about but couldn't quite phrased it well. This might be better for a different question, but can we tell (like some kind of a thumb rule, maybe certain questions for one and certain questions for the other) when we're going from natural science to metaphysics? Although it's not like metaphysics/science are historically universal terms, so maybe I should add "today".

Comment: I think it is better to distinguish them as different *aspects* of an activity rather than separate activities, although of course we could then distinguish activities by whichever aspect predominates. In the scientific aspect we make and "test" predictive models, but "tests" may be against common sense and intuition, as philosophers favor.  Models may in principle be purely statistical fits, although those are not great models. In interpretation we supply them with "pictures" and discern "hidden patterns" to better organize what they have to offer, and for that we imagine and speculate.

Comment: @Conifold wait so, the interpretation is the metaphysics aspect? Not sure I quite understood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73799/discussion-between-conifold-and-yechiam-weiss).

Comment: For me it would be about testability. Scientific theories can be tested empirically (via sensory data). Metaphysical (meta-empirical) theories have to be tested in logic or non-empirical experience, The natural sciences do not examine ontology because this is not their task and they do not have the methods. Metaphysics need have no respect for scientific theories but must always respect the data and It must explain that data.  Without empirical data there would be no reason for ontology to exist.

Comment: It occurs to me that this discussion is a bit odd when the definitions for 'physics' and 'metaphysics' can be found in a dictionary. .

Answer (score 1):

Metaphysics stands before and after physics. It surrounds physics, standing between physics and Reality and a fundamental theory. Physics is not fundamental and will never have such a theory. If we want a fundamental theory we must study metaphysics. That is to say, if we want to explain the phenomena studied by physics we must transcend physics.

Metaphysics must always take full account of physics and should explain it. Chalmers' article illustrates the relationship. The problem of consciousness, the inscrutability of matter etc., must be taken into account and explained within a metaphysical theory if the theory is to be plausible and useful.

Metaphysics is the boardroom of knowledge where the big decisions are taken. The natural sciences form a working party dealing with the world of appearances and reporting back to the the Board. The Board must take full account of these reports but its task takes it well beyond the limited realm of the empirical sciences.

Comment: I like how you keep this thread alive :) and wow, I never thought of metaphysics in the analogy you use in the last paragraph. I wonder though if contemporary philosophy treat metaphysics-physics relation that way.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - Mainstream contemporary philosophy seems to care little for metaphysics. (With, I would say, predictable results). ,.

Comment: and non-mainstream? You have anyone in mind for me to read?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - Names that come to mind are Francis Bradley (Appearance and Reality), Hermann Weyl (Open World) Nagarjuna,(Fundamental Verses)  George Spencer Brown (Laws of Form) , Paul Davies (Mind of God). These are some of my favourites. Other metaphyscians are usually good at proving that  metaphysics does not produce a positive result but are rarely able to comprehend what this implies and so give up (Russell, Carnap, Dennett, Chalmers etc)  .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a rather difficult question to address directly/compactly, but here's my take:

Firstly, "science" is a term that requires clarification. The existing practice of science involves both predictions of observable phenomena and also explanations (models, theories) of such phenomena.

Now, every metaphysical theory essentially has to accept the "predictive" aspect of science. For example, if you have a metaphysical theory that asserts purely divine mechanisms of disease and cure, and you refuse to use the scientific fact that antibiotics cure bacterial infections, pretty soon you'll run out of adherents. So all viable metaphysical theories have to accept/adjust to the "strong" facts (i.e. predictable patterns) that science discovers about the manifest world.

However, when we talk about the "explanatory" aspect of science, which pretty much always involves the use of certain entities or abstractions that are not directly observable, these explanations themselves are essentially (or at least heavily) metaphysics -- certainly in a positivist/empiricist sense. For example, science used to refer to something called "phlogiston" to explain the phenomena of burning; we know that it was a purely metaphysical entity, because it turned out not to exist! And nowadays we can talk about "gravity", which used to be considered a "force", but now is perhaps thought to be some characteristic of "curvature of spacetime", and in the future may get discarded in favor of another explanatory entity. Incidentally, there is nothing wrong with this -- science advances by testing various "metaphysical" models and keeping those that do not contradict observations. But it would be misleading, I think, to think of "science" and "metaphysics" as some completely unrelated intellectual pursuits, because at least the practice of science certainly involves metaphysics to a significant extent.

To summarize so far:
1. When it comes to prediction of observed phenomena in the manifest world, any metaphysical theory has to yield to science (and indeed whatever can be predicted accurately immediately becomes part of science).
2. When it comes to explanations of either the manifest or some kind of other "ultimate" reality, one can't easily contrast metaphysical vs. "scientific" explanation, because *any* such explanation can be viewed as fundamentally metaphysical -- as soon as it involves something that's not directly observable.

So, at best, we can perhaps ask whether a particular metaphysical theory A does (or should) accept another metaphysical theory B that is prevalent in the scientific community. And I can't think of any generic answer here. It may, but it doesn't have to, and often doesn't. Which is not particularly surprising, for even within the scientific community, at various times different groups of scientists also prefer different (explanatory) theories.

IMO, it comes down to the criteria by which to judge the goodness of an explanatory (metaphysical) theory. Scientific theories tend to be more economical (in the use of unobservabe entities), designed to be falsifiable in some way, reuse existing terms from accepted theories, etc. "General" metaphysical theories tend to focus on a certain kind of simplicity, or aesthetic beauty, or ethical considerations, or emotional needs, etc. Whatever one thinks are the most important criteria (of explanation) will guide one's choice of theory. And then one will tend to view other theories, including scientific ones, also in terms of how well they satisfy one's preferred criteria.

For example, if your preferred criteria is to minimize the number of unobservable entities in a theory, you might choose/build a metaphysical theory that mimics existing scientific theories, re-uses some of the same terms (e.g. "quantum entanglement"), etc. Or, you might minimize the unobservables by choosing a theory where "everything" is explainable in terms of a single unobservable Being. In both cases, you'd likely prefer to fly on a plane built using "pure" scientific facts (i.e. wings generate lift, etc); but your explanations might range from a (scientific) "this is simply how the universe works" to a (theistic) "this is how Being designed this universe to work".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest whether or not "metaphysics should care about physics" all depends on how close current physical theory actually is to the "ultimate truth" (whatever that might be, if it even exists).

On the one hand, suppose current physical theory is indeed very close to the so-called "theory of everything", and that only a few more bells-and-whistles are needed to construct a completely satisfactory theory of all existence, with no loose ends remaining whatsoever. Then, yeah, metaphysics should care lots about what physics is saying, because the entire metaphysics programme would just amount to an interpretation of exactly that perfect final theory.

On the other hand, ancient Greek metaphysicians would have been well-advised not to care about the epicycle theory of planetary motion, which was based on the topsy-turvy wrong idea that the Sun and planets revolve around the Earth (at least they got it right about the Moon). So grounding your metaphysics on that entirely wrong physics gets you nowhere: garbage-in, garbage-out.

So is today's physics finally barking up the right metaphysical tree, or is it just an epicycles-like numbers game intricately manipulated to obtain results that agree with observations, but based on an entirely erroneous conception of reality? If forced to place a bet, I'd personally bet on erroneous simply due to the odds, i.e., "there are more things in heaven and earth...". Moreover, it's more metaphysical fun to dream up something entirely new, but then it's dangerous to take such dreams too seriously, which seems to be an under-recognized problem by some metaphysicians.

**Edit (reply to @YechiamWeiss comment)**

*copy of Y.W.'s comment***:**   It seems to me like you're switching the metaphysics and physics in their relation - it's physics that's (supposedly) built upon metaphysics, not the other way around.

Maybe metaphysicians (philosophers of science) think physics is "supposedly built" [your words] on metaphysics, but that's not what the physicists doing the actual building think. And although they (physicists) typically can't help having some metaphysical predispositions, that isn't typically the ultimate determining factor in the direction of their research. Experimental observations and then mathematical elegance more typically are. In the long run, an elegant metaphysics that's also consistent with the physics hopefully emerges, in which case you can reconstruct the entire edifice as though ground-up/*ab initio* based on the foundational metaphysics. And that'll be more elegant, but it won't be what historically happened.

To wit, note the "shut up and calculate" school of thought https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Shut_up_and_calculate which explicitly (and maybe a little facetiously) downplays any role for metaphysics, although the "shut up and contemplate" alternative also cited there somewhat softens that position.

There may be some philosophers who hold the "physics that's (supposedly) built upon metaphysics" position, but in my opinion that's pretty (and totally unjustifiably) pompous. It presupposes the intelligence/insight/whatever to more-or-less foundationally intuit the world through pure thought alone. However, for example, there's not one single philosopher nor one single physicist who anticipated any of the non-classical aspects of the world that came to light in the twentieth (and very late nineteenth) century. Everybody got dragged kicking and screaming into that new view of reality. But at least the physicists completely openly admitted their own prior stupidity (okay, eventually admitted), whereas my sense is that philosophers aren't quite so open about that (although I know next-to-nothing about it).

In any case, admitted or not, it's true. And that suggests experimental evidence is a necessary crutch for human thought about the nature of the world. It happened with epicycles, it happened with phlogiston, with the atomic/molecular theory of matter/chemistry, with non-Galilean relativity, with discrete quanta, etc, etc. So are you now trying to tell me that philosophers are finally equipped with everything they need to know, whereby their pure thought alone will come up with the correct foundational picture of the world??? I don't think so!!!

Comment: It seems to me like you're switching the metaphysics and physics in their relation - it's physics that's (supposedly) build upon metaphysics, not the other way around.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss please see "edit" above for (too lengthy for comment) reply to your comment.

Comment: You're assuming metaphysics stands on its own and physics stands on its own. "philosophers are equipped with everything they need to know, whereby their pure thought alone will come up with the correct foundational picture of the world", is one field of metaphysics, usually called speculative natural philosophy (which is, admittedly sadly for me, pretty much gone now). Metaphysics isn't only that. It's also the thought of how we perceive the world, how the world is build prior to the empirical research-

Comment: and even the "shut up and calculate" thought is inherently based on metaphysical assumption - that which is often called positivism.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Re "It's also the thought of how we perceive the world, how the world is build [note: that should be "built"] prior to the empirical research", okay, my bad. I'm apparently barking up the wrong tree with respect to your question. Indeed, I was only vaguely aware of your tree. I think physics necessarily (it has no other choice) interprets perception with respect to the **verifiably reproducible behavior of well-defined apparatus**. Beyond that, consciousness/perception/qualia/whatever, is beyond the realm of physics. So in that realm, you shouldn't even be mentioning physics.

Comment: partially agreed. I'm contemplating whether or not physics can help understand metaphysical subjects such as consciousness, perception, etc (materialists would obviously state that it's the only way). And do note that "verifiably reproducible behavior of well-defined apparatus", is a philosophy-of-science' metaphysical claim (which brings us the best natural science we currently have).